# How to make the modebar in plotly graphs for R shiny permanently show?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

So by default, the modebar for Plotly graphs appears when you hover your mouse over it...but is there a way to make it always show (without hovering)?

I've found an easy way to disable it, but is there a similar option for the hover functionality?

Example:

```
plot_ly() %>%
  config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
```

from:
https://plotly-r.com/control-modebar.html

Thanks!!

Comment: You just want to be able to have the `displayModeBar` to always show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by changing `displayModeBar = FALSE` to `displayModeBar = TRUE`

Example data obtained from [here](https://plotly.com/r/box-plots/)

```
fig <- plot_ly(y = ~rnorm(50), type = "box")
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~rnorm(50, 1))  %>%
  config(displayModeBar = TRUE)

fig
```

[image: example]